# Kafka Streams: Internal topic partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka version: 1.0.0 
Let's say the stream application uses low level processor API which maintains the state and reads from a topic with 10 partitions.  Please clarify if the internal topic is expected to be created with the same number of partitions OR is it per the broker default.  If it's the later, if we need to increase the partitions of the internal topic, is there any option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kafka Streams will create the topic for you. And yes, it will create it with the same number of partitions as your input topic. During startup, Kafka Streams also checks if the topic has the expected number of partitions and fails if not.

The internal topic is basically a regular topic as any other and you can change the number of partitions via command line tools like for any other topic. However, this should never be required. Also note, that dropping/adding partitions, will mess up your state.

Comment: hey Matthias, is there somewhere documented dos/dont's of adding new partitions to a running topic (with or without downtime) for a Kafka streams app? For scalability reasons we are forced to add new partitions. I tested adding new partitions and gets `could not create internal topics` on the running consumer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is much in the docs :( -- Feel free to contribute! -- However, you cannot change the number of partitions if you have any stateful operations (aggregations/joins). If you need to change the number of partitions, you will need to reset your application: https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, What about the replication factor of internal topics? Does internal topic also has same replication factor as input topic ?

Comment: You can configure the replication factor for internal topics using `replication.factor` parameter in the Streams configuration. In newer versions the default is set to `-1`, meaning broker default. In older versions it's set to `1`, and thus it recommended to change for production. (Note, the config only applies if internal topics are newly created. Existing topics are not reconfigured if you change the config later.)