# When you change number of partitions for user kafka topic, will the Kafka stream adjust number of partitions for internal topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka Stream which is created from 3 topics:

- topic1 4 partitions
- topic2 1 partition
- topic3 1 partiton.

Kafka stream created internal topic with value of max(4,1,1) which would be 4 partitions.

Recently we had to change number partitions of topic2 and topic3 to 6.

My question is what will happen with kafka streams internal topic? Will it pick up the new max partition? Or will it throw an error like

> ...expected number of partitions 6 but found 4.

If the partition reassginment doesn't happen automagically is there any way to make it so that the changes are picked up after service restart? Or manual actions are the only options here.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275861/kafka-streams-internal-topic-partitions